# How to redefine this integral so it meets some requirements, $\int g(x)\ln|x| \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $$ G(t)=\int_{0}^{t} g(x)\ln|x| \mathrm dx$$

Give conditions over $g(x)$ so that $G$

1.It is defined near $0$.

2.Be continuous in $t=0$.

3.Be derivable near $0$

4.Give the value of $$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{G(t)}{3t}$$

---

Questions about reasoning:

1. I have several questions about this. First of all, if a function (in this case G) is defined with an integral, can it not be be defined, in this case, in $0$. Is it an improper Integral
2. If i define g(x) so that $g(x)\ln|x|$ is continuous in t=0 that would mean(by theorem) that $g(x)\ln|x|$ can be integrated there and by, another theorem, that G is continuous ?

I don't know. Any help thinking this through ?

Comment: Please don't put tags in the heading. We will see the tags anyway.

Comment: If I were to give a function, I would choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{\ln|x|}$. Then $G(t)=t$, because the undefined parts in $-1,0,1$ don't matter for the integral as far as I know. But you sounded like wanting general conditions for $g$, right? In that case I'm just wondering why you accepted the other answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take $$g(x)=x$$.

Then $$G(t)=\ln|t|\frac{t^2}2-\frac{t^2}4$$

It can be easily seen that all requirements are met and the limit is $0$.

Comment: altough it is not define in 0, is it ok ?

Comment: $G(0)$ is undefined, so it doesn’t satisfy the conditions given by the asker

Comment: @MJW I think $G(0)=0$, but still doesn't satisfy conditions because it won't be continuous, right?

Comment: @SK19 ln 0 is undefined

Comment: @MJW https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Conventions I rest my case.

Comment: @MJW G(0) is undefined, but the asker didn’t require it to be defined; it is required G(t) to be defined NEAR 0.

Comment: @SK19 It is continuous. You may convince yourself by plotting G(t).